# What is the meaning of monotonicity in C++ n2660?

Tags: c++

In "http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2660.htm"

That says

> [monotonicity] Accesses to a single variable V of type T by a single
>   thread X appear to occur in programme order. For example, if V is
>   initially 0, then X writes 1, and then 2 to V, no thread (including
>   but not limited to X) can read a value from V and then subsequently
>   read a lower value from V. (Notice that this does not prevent
>   arbitrary load and store reordering; it constrains ordering only
>   between actions on a single memory location. This assumption is
>   reasonable on all architectures that I currently know about. I suspect
>   that the Java and CLR memory models require this assumption also.)

I can't understand relationship between call_once and monotonicity.

And can't find related document about it.

Please, help.

Comment: The document suggests an implementation of `call_once` that doesn't need a memory barrier in the "short" path (after the initialization has happened). This impl relies on the standard guarantees of monotonicity- and atomicity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the compiler won't reorder actions done on the same memory spot.
So if you write:

```
int i = 0;
i = 1;
i = 2;
```

There is no way your current thread or another will read the `i` variable with a value of `2` then read the same variable to find out the value `1` or `0`.

In the linked paper it is used as a requirement for the given `pthread_once` implementation, so if this principle is not respected, that implementation might not work. The reason of this added requirement seems to be to avoid a memory barrier to gain performance.

Answer (score 2):

Monotonicity means: If operation B is issued after operation A, then B cannot be executed before A.

The explanation given in the text stems from mathematics, where a monotonic series is one that only ever moves up or down: 1, 2, 7, 11 is monotonic (each value is bigger than the one before), as is 100, 78, 39, 12 (each value is smaller than the one before), 16, 5, 30 isn't monotonic.

If a value is modified in strictly ascending order, any two reads will lead to two results a, b with b >= a - the monotonicity is kept.

Comment: I'd like to add to Lying Dog's answer that monotonic can include points that do not move at all.